# system.invalidoperationexception linqtosql debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

i know this question have been asked before, but the solution is to go to the menu DEBUG and Exceptions and add under common the invalidoperationexception and then debug again. The debugger is then supposed to just straight to the line that is the reason for the exception to be thrown, but it doesn't. It jump constantly to db.SubmitChanges.

I am trying to uncomment and comment lines for approaching it this way and i found out that this line is causing it:

```
db.CasePhotos.InsertAllOnSubmit(this._casePhotos);
```

I use a codefirst approach because the database is isostore for windows phone.

The class CasePhoto contains an Association to the class Case.

This is how my CasePhoto Association looks like:

```
    [Column]
    public int CaseId;

    private EntityRef<Case> _Case;
    [Association(Storage = "_Case", ThisKey = "CaseId"]
    public Case Case
    {
        get { return this._Case.Entity; }
        set { this._Case.Entity = value; }
    }
```

The problem is obviously the association.

The Case exists, but the only thing i am doing is to assign the newly created case id to the associated key, like this:

```
item.CaseId = newCaseId;
```

What is it that i am doing wrong? I have also tried to add the whole object to the "Case" property, but no luck.

### How do i correcly assign a value to a field that is associated/in relation with another field?